# Aceitar somente números no aplicativo console C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variáveis

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer com que o comando Console.ReadLine() leia somente números, ignorando caracteres, tem algum jeito ?

exemplo:

```
static void main()
{
    int x;

    Console.WriteLine("INSERINDO VALOR PARA X");

    x=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) //em execução quero que o console só aceite números inteiros do teclado.

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas resoluções, consegui implementar em meu código, mas estou tendo dificuldades para apagar a tecla que foi digitada, no caso de clique errado. Alterei esse código para reconhecer o Backspace más ele trava o console.

Comment: Mas esse comentário é dirigido para quem? Para mim ou para Daniel. Quando assim faça o comentário na resposta, pressionando o botão `comentar` em baixo da resposta, que assim o autor da resposta será notificado.

Comment: Se é C# por quê a tag C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode implementar um método que faça a leitura exclusiva de números pressionados dentro do `Console`.
Para isso você terá iniciar um loop e terá que testar a cada iteração se uma tecla foi pressionada com [`Console.KeyAvailable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_KeyAvailable) que retorna um booleano indicando se houve o pressionar de uma tecla.

Se `Console.KeyAvailable` acusar um pressionar de teclas é instruir a leitura da tecla com [`Console.ReadKey();`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8) passando `true` como primeiro parâmetro de forma a evitar que a tecla lida seja impressa na tela do 'Console'.

Então teste a natureza da tecla pressionada:

- Se for um número acumule na `string` de retorno do método.
- Se for a tecla enter encerra a iteração.
- Se a tecla for back space remove o último caractere do console(vide altrações no código).
- Qualquer outro valor ignore.

Usando `switch case when` com a sintaxe da versão 7 ou superior do `C#`:

```
using System;

class Exemplo
{
    public static string lerNumeros()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        string entrada = "";
        bool continuarLoop = true;
        while (continuarLoop)
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                switch (cki.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                        if (entrada.Length == 0) continue;
                        entrada = entrada.Remove(entrada.Length - 1);
                        Console.Write("\b \b"); //Remove o último caractere digitado
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                        continuarLoop = false;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey key when ((ConsoleKey.D0 <= key) && (key <= ConsoleKey.D9) ||                       
                                              (ConsoleKey.NumPad0 <= key) && (key <= ConsoleKey.NumPad9)):
                        entrada += cki.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);
                        break;
                }
            }
        return entrada;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insira o valor para X.");


        int x = int.Parse(lerNumeros());

        Console.WriteLine("\nO valor de X é '{0}'.", x);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Usando `if` independente da versão da linguagem:

```
using System;

class Exemplo
{
    public static string lerNumeros()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        string entrada = "";            
        while (true)
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace){
                    if (entrada.Length == 0) continue;
                    entrada = entrada.Remove(entrada.Length - 1);
                    Console.Write("\b \b"); //Remove o último caractere digitado
                }    
                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if ((ConsoleKey.D0 <= cki.Key) && (cki.Key <= ConsoleKey.D9) ||
                    (ConsoleKey.NumPad0 <= cki.Key) && (cki.Key <= ConsoleKey.NumPad9))
                {
                    entrada += cki.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);
                }

            }
        return entrada;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insira o valor para X.");


        int x = int.Parse(lerNumeros());

        Console.WriteLine("\nO valor de X é '{0}'.", x);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CheapSpecificFraction)

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema com esses exemplos, só falta a parte de incluir o backspace que ainda estou verificando. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Gabriel, se existe alguma forma nativa de fazer isso, desculpe mas não conheço.

Geralmente, as pessoas adotam um loop que mantém o usuário "preso" enquanto o que ele digitar não for um número, sendo que o cast é feito de uma forma que não gera exceção.

Veja um exemplo:

```
using System;

class ReadLineInt {
  static void Main() {
    int x;

    Console.WriteLine("INSERINDO VALOR PARA X");

    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x)) {
         Console.WriteLine("Insira apenas números inteiros");
         Console.WriteLine("INSERINDO VALOR PARA X");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Número digitado: " + x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interessante, vou adaptar este exemplo para ver como fica, muito obrigado.